# Get countinuous json data from server before connection close in ktor client

Tags: kotlin, ktor, ktor-client

I'm using ktor client in my android project and I want to get countinous data before I can close the connection. Here is the example of nodeJS app that give data countinuosly.

```js
const app = require("express")()
let count = 0

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    }
    res.writeHead(200, headers)

    setInterval(() => {
        res.write({data: count})
        count++
    }, 2000);
})

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("ok"))
```

I don't know how to implement this, and I couldn't find anything on the internet also. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can read data from a response stream as soon as it becomes available for the client. Here is an example:

```
val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(HttpTimeout)
}
client.prepareGet("http://localhost:3000/") {
    timeout {
        requestTimeoutMillis = Long.MAX_VALUE
    }
}.execute { response ->
    val channel = response.bodyAsChannel()

    while (!channel.isClosedForRead) {
        val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024)
        val read = channel.readAvailable(buffer)
        if (read == -1) break
        buffer.flip()
        val jsonString = Charsets.UTF_8.decode(buffer).toString()
        println(jsonString)
    }
}
```